# Updating profile in Adonisjs

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to update profile but i'm getting status 400 whats i'm doing wrong?

```
async update({ request, auth, response }) {
        try {
            const user = auth.current.User
            user.firstName = request.input('firstName')
            user.lastName = request.input('lastName')
            user.email = request.input('email')
            user.password = request.input('password')

            await user.save()

            return response.json({
                status: 'success',
                message: 'Profile updated!',
                data: user
            })
        } catch (error) {
            return response.status(400).json({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'There was a problem updating profile, please try again later.'
            })
        }
    }
```

I just started learning node.js and addonis. how can i add validator on password? so password must be confirmed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
async update({ request, auth, response }) {
        try {
            const user = auth.current.User
            user.firstName = request.input('firstName')
            user.lastName = request.input('lastName')
            user.email = request.input('email')
            user.password = request.input('password')

            await user.save()

            return response.json({
                status: 'success',
                message: 'Profile updated!',
                data: user
            })
        } catch (error) {
            return response.status(500).json(error);
        }
    }
```

**Now we'll get exactly what error occurs let me know which error occurs when we are trying to save user**

Comment: I'm not getting exactly error in postman i'm getting 500 error

Comment: try to log error in catch block console.log(error)

Comment: Or try to debug your code with brake points

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')  it can't read auth.current.User  but i added in top import User from 'App/Models/User'  but it is not reading it

Comment: any help ? ....

Comment: Okei now I totally understand, If you want to update a user you have to first find the user then you can change the database record with input record

Comment: Which ORM you are using Mongoose or Sequlize?